# WebStorm keeps indexing with slight changes

Tags: indexing, angular, webstorm, seed

I'm currently using WebStorm build 11.0.3, to do some Angular 2 programming/learning and I'm using Angular 2 seed.

WebStorm keeps indexing after every few changes and/or some minutes...

Any suggestions or advises? I'm sure there are some settings about this but I didn't find any.

Comment: I had the same or similar with an `xxx.md` file not too long ago. I fixed it by deleting the file. That's probably not the solution you're looking for. I suggest to create a bug report.

Comment: Check what `idea.log` may have to say (`Help | Show Log in...`)

Comment: This is the issue I created a while back https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19744

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ...and did you do what devs asked you (supply logs to see what may be causing such behaviour)?I'm asking because I see no attachments anywhere in that ticket.

Comment: No, not yet. The attachment might be private, don't remember.

Comment: Hi there, well i "solved" it by upgrading to the newest 2016.1 version...now the indexing is super fast.

Answer (score 2):

Because the angular seed folder contains too many files, or others folders, go to webstorm preference, select menu "Directories ", select the fold that you want to Exclude, click "Exclude", then click "Apply" and "OK". As the following picture shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **FILE** and click on **invalidate caches and restart**.

Answer (score 0):

Also, If you are running Unit Test make sure to exclude the Coverage folder. otherwise, it will keep indexing every time you run a Unit test.
Just right click on the folder name and chose exclude.